# Databinding from within a template in angular

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular2-nativescript

In a component how to databind two-way for the following example:
I want the button's text to toggle automatically when I am setting or unsetting `dataitem.isSelected` in the respective methods

Here is the code of channelstab.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'channels-tab',
  template: `
    <ListView [items]="channels$ | async" class="list-group">
        <ng-template let-dataitem="item">
           <Button [text]="dataitem.isSelected?'UnFollow':'follow'" (tap)="dataitem.isSelected?unfollow(dataitem):follow(dataitem)"></Button>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChannelsTabComponent implements OnInit {
     public channels$: Observable<any>;
     ngOnInit() {
       this.channels$ = <any>this.someService.get('channels');
     }
     unfollow(dataitem) {
        dataitem.isSelected = false;//not working
     }
     follow(dataitem) {
        dataitem.isSelected = true;//not working
     }
}
```

Comment: where are these functions defined?

Comment: within same component, updated the code to include other parts .

Comment: try removing this `let-dataitem="item"`, it should read `dataitem` from the context of the component

Comment: Changing ChangeDetectionStrategy from OnPush  to Default seemed to have solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this part `let-dataitem="item"` from here `<ng-template let-dataitem="item">`:

```
<ListView [items]="channels$ | async" class="list-group">
    <ng-template>
       <Button [text]="dataitem.isSelected?'UnFollow':'follow'" (tap)="dataitem.isSelected?unfollow(dataitem):follow(dataitem)"></Button>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

Embedded views that are created from the `ng-template` have access to the properties on the parent component, so it should be updated whenever Angular runs change detection. [Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6A3UZnvQ85vdqT6ttfYk?p=preview) and the code that emulates your case:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: `{{name}}`
})
export class TestComponent {
  @Input() name;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ng-template #t>
      <test [name]="name"></test>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container #vc></ng-container>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc;
  @ViewChild('t', {read: TemplateRef}) t;

  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;

    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.name='changed';
    }, 3000);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.vc.createEmbeddedView(this.t);
  }
}
```

Comment: I still can't understand it properly, how can it read `dataitem` from component. In component's constuctor I only have `channel$` which is an Observable. Can you point me to an looping over an Observable in template example ?

Comment: or better yet create a simple plunker

Comment: plunker would look something like this https://plnkr.co/edit/aUergVKO3W7WQmdAn8m7?p=preview

Comment: plunker is not working, make sure it works so I can take a look

Comment: it's a mobile app.plunker won't work.tried to replace listview with ul but not sure how plunker computes.

Comment: you can write your own simple `listview` component and use it instead of `ul`. where does `item` come from here `let-dataitem="item"`?

Comment: items comes from RxJs Observable channels$. My understanding is `item` in `ng-template let-dataitem="item"` is singular of that .

Comment: no, that is not the case. I need to see the code for the ListView component as well

Comment: here is the docs https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/ui/listview.html#creating-listview

Comment: I see, One problem is that you can't use `observable` there. You will always have only one `<Button ` rendered because observable emits values one by one. Is that the case for your? Let's try to make it work for the simple array, ok?

Comment: I am able to render the full list via observable as one of the exmples down there show, on Listview level i can also have onItemTap() to get the index, but not able to access the observable index like array. So was thinking if I could solve it with something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537383/get-array-element-in-observable-at-particular-index-html

Comment: I'll think later

Comment: what does your observable return? what data?

Comment: what data as in ? just an object with key-value pairs, accepted as json.

Comment: any new thoughts? Maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: sorry, not enough information to answer the question, it'd be great if you could put up a plunker has the as many details as possible

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: @Maximus: not sure it's possible to do plunk for a mobile app.if you have android sdk and tns setup on your system, you an just clone https://github.com/ishandutta2007/fast and run `tns run android`