# how to get all switch control value from listview row items in order in angular2 nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm using modal dialog when clicking on button. In that, I'm using switch control in listview.

For every row item in listview, I need to perform switch control to get the value.

**Edited:**

**app.modal.html:**

```
  <ListView  [items]="getListData" class="list" height="160">
        <ng-template let-item="item" let-myIndex="index">

            <GridLayout rows="*" columns="1.5*, auto, auto">

                    <Label row="0" col="0" class="item-name" [text]="item.category" ></Label>

                    <Switch row="0" col="1" [checked]="item.toggleVal" (checkedChange)="onFirstChecked($event, myIndex)"></Switch>

                    <Image row="0" col="2" src="res://menu_alert" stretch="none"></Image>

            </GridLayout>

        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
```

**app.modal.ts file:**

```
public map: Map<number, boolean>;

public newFeedsList: Array<NewFeed> = [];

public constructor(private params: ModalDialogParams) {


this.map = new Map<number, boolean>();


}

  public onFirstChecked(args, index: number) {

     let firstSwitch = <Switch>args.object;

     if(index != null && firstSwitch.checked){

        this.map.set(this.newFeedsList[index].id , firstSwitch.checked);


        console.log("Map :",this.map);
        console.log("Map :", JSON.stringify(this.map));


      } else {


      }

    }
```

**NewFeed.ts:**

```
export class NewFeed {
constructor(public id: number,public toggleVal : string, public title: string, public description:string, public date:string,public category:string, public imageUrl:string,public iconName:string) {}

}
```

So When I'm enabling the switch in listview row items, I'm storing the index in Array.

**What is Happening:**

Right now I'm unable to print the hash map in console. It is showing `Map:[object Map]` in console.

**What I need:**

When I'm click on switch in listview row items, it has to get the NewFeed id and toggleVal as a key and value. So that I used map.

In that I'm saving id as key and toggleVal as Value in map.But I'm unable to add the id and toggleVal in map.so i don't know whether those two values were added in map.

It should change in the same position, if we switch single listview row items 'n' number of times.

Comment: is this similar ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198044/databinding-from-within-a-template-in-angular/45199711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not saving it by index = value? you will get an array of value like:

```
[
    true,  //index 0 is checked
    false, //index 1 is unchecked
    true,  //index 2 is checked
    ...    //globally index n is value
]
```

and to build it like:

```
public onFirstChecked(args, index: number) {
    let firstSwitch = <Switch>args.object; 
    //always assign whenever it is checked or not
    Global.newFeedArr[index] = firstSwitch.checked; 
}
```

**Update**:

By using the [Map class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) like you do, and storing value whenever it's checked or not:

```
public map: Map<number, boolean>;
constructor() {
    this.map = new Map<number, boolean>();
}
public onFirstChecked(args, index: number) {
    let firstSwitch = <Switch>args.object;
    this.map.set(this. newFeedsList[index].id, firstSwitch.checked);
    //this is a debug to display current entries
    console.log('this.map entries are:');
    this.map.forEach(function (value, key) {
        console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
    });
}
```

Comment: My newFeedArr seems to be like this :  `public static newFeedArr : Array<
NewFeed> = [];`   I'm using this array as global to access everywhere. In `NewFeed` separate pojo model class, I'm having id and boolean value. So I need to perform key and Value like  [{ id= true, id=false,.. } ]  it should take the same id position everytime whenever we switching control on same listview row item.

Comment: How's NewFeed class defined? you say [{ id= true, id=false,.. } ] , should not [{ id= true}, {id=false}... ] ?

Comment: please check my edited post. I clearly added everything what I'm tried so far.

Comment: I updated the answer with map class, you will not get a value with your console.log